# EKS (AWS) and GKE k8s clusters how to create nodes without node group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks

I found many nodes without `eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup` label

from [Amazon EKS - API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/APIReference/API_Nodegroup.html) it seems normal:

> The name associated with an Amazon EKS managed node group.
> Type: String
> Required: No

is it common?
I don't understand how can I create on EKS nodes without nodegroup?
I found this information:
Launch EC2 instances with an IAM role for EKS access.
Manually configure Kubernetes on the instances, join them to the EKS cluster.
is it possible also on GKE?

Answer (score 2):

On the GKE side, it is technically possible to do it, but it's not documented or  really supported.

Comment: Is there any information that supports this? How can I do this? Is it common?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve or why do you want to create your own nodes versus using node pools?